# memoir: Same headers in table of contents as in frontmatter chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

I would like to use the same header and footer scheme in the table of contents as in the frontmatter's chapters. That is, no header on the first page of the ToC and then the chapter title ("Contents") in all small caps in the header. (In the example below, the ToC header shows the chapter title in all caps.)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\textsc{\thepage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\textsc{\thepage}}{}

\copypagestyle{main}{plain}
\makeevenhead{main}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \rightmark}}{}
\makeoddhead{main}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \leftmark}}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}
\copypagestyle{front}{main}
\makeevenhead{front}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \leftmark}}{}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \pagestyle{front}
  \tableofcontents*
  \clearpage
  \chapter{An unnumbered chapter}
  \Blindtext[4]
  \mainmatter
  \pagestyle{main}
  \chapter{A numbered chapter}
  \Blindtext[4]
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
\end{document}
```

My best attempt thus far is to set

```
\renewcommand{\tocmark}[1]{\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}
```

and then write the frontmatter part like so:

```
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{front}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\chapter{An unnumbered chapter}
\Blindtext[4]
```

but, while the headers and footers then look as requested, this makes the title on the first page of the ToC a weird "Contentschapter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things look as requested if you add `\def\tocmark{\markboth{\contentsname}{}}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\textsc{\thepage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\textsc{\thepage}}{}

\copypagestyle{main}{plain}
\makeevenhead{main}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \rightmark}}{}
\makeoddhead{main}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \leftmark}}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}
\copypagestyle{front}{main}
\makeevenhead{front}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape \leftmark}}{}
\def\tocmark{\markboth{\contentsname}{}}% This is added
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \pagestyle{front}
  \tableofcontents*
  \clearpage
  \chapter{An unnumbered chapter}
  \Blindtext[4]
  \mainmatter
  \pagestyle{main}
  \chapter{A numbered chapter}
  \Blindtext[4]
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
  \chapter{More chapters to make table of contents stretch over three pages}
\end{document}
```